# Permission Denied Error ('[Errno 13]') when Loading Data in Python with OpenAI API

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, openai-api, windows-11

I am currently working on a small application utilizing the OpenAI API, and I'm encountering an error that I need help with. When attempting to load the data, I receive the following error message:

```
[Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:\\Users\\punee\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp67r_48t6'
```

I would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue. My objective is to successfully load the data without encountering this permission-denied error.

Thank you in advance for your help!

[I am getting this error in jupyter-notebook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqTbR.png)

Comment: You need to: show the code that reads this file; check which user is executing the code; check the permission on the file.